# KDE - Windows, etc "stick" to Pointer when button not being held

Tags: kde, window-manager, window-decorations

Often in KDE (on CentOS 7.2), I left-click on a window or other element to bring it to focus, but the element "sticks" to my pointer, as if I am "click dragging" the item - to spite the fact that the mouse-button is not being held down.

I have to move the pointer/item back "where it was" and left-click again, so it will "drop" the element.

Perhaps this happens because my mouse is not perfectly still when I click the element?

Is this "auto-drag without holding the button" experience a "feature"?
If so, how do I disable it?